# Expanding Java Regex to match word containing certain string

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

So I've got this regex:

```
String tagsRegex = "^(" + String.join("|", tags) + ")$";
```

Which will match everything being exactly the string `tags`. For instance, if `tags` is `john`, it will match JUST `john` but not `johnny` or `thejohnman`.

What I want is to match `*tag*`, in other words I want to match every word which contains the string stored in the variable `tag`.

Any  hint?

Comment: You could try making your tags in form like `\w*john\w*`.

Comment: What don't you get, @KickButtowski?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using your regex as:

```
String tagsRegex = "\\w*(" + String.join("|", tags) + ")\\w*";
```

This is assuming your array `tags` doesn't have any elements with special regex symbols such as `[()*+]` etc.

With above if array `tags` is: `{"foo", "bar", "baz"}` then built regex will be:

```
\w*(foo|bar|baz)\w*
```

Comment: Could you please explain your regex so I can learn and vote you?

Comment: Actually it is a small modification of your own regex. My changes are adding `\w*` on either side of the group instead of `^` and `$` you are using. `\w*` on either side allows 0 or more word characters on either side of word in `tags` array.